# Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am getting below error while starting the application, I get this exception only when I add `@cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` annotation on the domain object. If I just use annotation `@Cacheable(true)` it does not give this error.

```
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
```

How is it possible that with just Cacheble it is able to find the factory and using `@Cache` annotation it isn't ?

persistence.xml

```
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

I am using Hibernate version 4.x JPA 2.1 on JBoss EAP 6

Comment: Any luck? Did u try the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try adding this to your class.  Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region="employee").

Change the region name to what you are using in you encache.xml

Comment: Did the above answer help?

Comment: Not yet, whatever is the result I will update you here only when I try. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Wc can you please accept the answer as well. Click the gray check mark under the vote buttons